# How to re-run 'postactivate' script within virtualenv?

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I created a virtualenv (called `rpi`) with a `postactivate` script (located in `~/virtualenvs/rpi/bin` that SSH's into an RPi. When I reboot the RPi, the SSH connections closes as expected. Is there a way to run the commands in `postactivate` again from within the `rpi` virtualenv? In other words, run `postactivate` without running `deactivate` and then `workon rpi`.

I tried just running `sudo ~/virtualenvs/rpi/bin/postactivate` in the terminal, but I get `command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with shell:

```
sh ~/virtualenvs/rpi/bin/postactivate
```

PS. Why `sudo`?

Comment: i think i used sudo because it gave me a permissions error when i just tried running the script without the `sh` or something